# I receive files every 15min. Should I use Cloud function or File Sensor in composer to trigger a DAG?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-composer

I receive files every 15 min into GCS bucket. I would like to use composer DAG to process that file.
But I am not sure on whether to use cloud function (event based trigger) to trigger DAG or use GCS sensor.

Each file has timestamp in it's name and I would like to skip processing the files with more than 30 min delay (If they arrive late).

Thanks in advance

Comment: In most cases use Cloud Functions. However, your question does not include information about what the processing requirements are.

Comment: Thank you @JohnHanley. Cloud function makes more sense, since file sensor for most part utilizes a slot in composer. And the process in DAG just get the file and load it into BigQuery.